# Vb6 Grouping Values in Flexgrid

Tags: vb6, cycle

I have a Flexgrid (vb6 not .Net) disconnected from any Db, having some rows like this:

```
135,00  4
218,00  4
100,00  10
6,00    4
15,00   22
```

I'm not able to create a cycle to obtain how many different groups (by vat) i have on the grid and calculate the relative amount so to have
3 Groups (in this case 4 / 10 / 22)
4 = 359,00 10 = 100 22 = 15,00
I don't want to use a database with select group by, rather pre-calculate the amount and visualize in n text box.

This is the code i have tried

```
Dim A, b, c, d 
if A = "" Then
A = xNum
  ElseIf A <> "" Then
 If A <> xNum Then
 If b = "" Then
   b = xNum
     ElseIf b <> "" Then
        If b <> xNum Then
          If c = "" Then
             c = xNum
              ElseIf c <> "" Then
                 If c <> xNum Then
                    If d = "" Then
                       d = xNum
                        ElseIf d <> "" Then [etc...]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have code where you've tried implementing this logic?  If so, could you post it?

Comment: Update your post with the code you tried, and then delete your comment.

Comment: thanks @brianMstafford

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using a Microsoft FlexGrid control where the first column is a quantity and the second column is the vat.

[image]

The following code will produce the results shown in the TextBox:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCalc_Click()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim c As Collection
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim g As Group
   Dim data As String

   'calculate groups
   Set c = New Collection

   For i = 1 To MSFlexGrid1.Rows - 1
      Set g = New Group
      g.VAT = CInt(MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(i, 2))
      g.Qty = CDbl(MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(i, 1))

      Err.Clear
      c.Add g, CStr(g.VAT)
      If Err.Number > 0 Then c(CStr(g.VAT)).Qty = c(CStr(g.VAT)).Qty + g.Qty
   Next

   'and visualize the data
   For Each g In c
      data = data & g.VAT & vbTab & g.Qty & vbCrLf
   Next

   Text1.Text = data
End Sub
```

The basic idea of this code is to build a collection of group objects, one group for each row in the grid.  As groups are being added to the collection, error trapping is utilized to detect duplicates and to increase the quantity in those cases.

Here is the `Group` class used by the above code:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_VAT As Integer
Private m_Qty As Double

Public Property Get VAT() As Integer
   VAT = m_VAT
End Property

Public Property Let VAT(ByVal Value As Integer)
   m_VAT = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Qty() As Double
   Qty = m_Qty
End Property

Public Property Let Qty(ByVal Value As Double)
   m_Qty = Value
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you so much Brian, it's absolutely perfect!  What you did was exactly what I wanted to accomplish but I had no idea how to do it. I will take inspiration from your code to always learn something. I have already tried it and it works perfectly. Thank you very much