# Group Values in Flexgrid Vb6

Tags: vb6, group, msflexgrid

I have a Flexgrid (vb6) disconnected from any Db, having some rows like sh:own in image below ... I'm not able to create a cycle to obtain how many different groups (by vat) i have on the grid and calculate the relative amount so to have .. as you see there is 2 groups in example ....
result should be like :

- A   405
- B   75

note : i see this post but could't use it .. there is error:  [Vb6 Grouping Values in Flexgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175323/vb6-grouping-values-in-flexgrid)

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?  What error are you receiving?  Add these to your question so we can help you.

Comment: hi brother ... I tried same your code in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175323/vb6-grouping-values-in-flexgrid .... error is in this code (Dim g As Group) ... error message is (User-defined type not defined) need your help  ... regards

Comment: here is proiect .. you can test it ..... https://www.mediafire.com/file/7315oe5gqbfigfi/Desktop.rar/file

Comment: still waiting any help !!!

Comment: Did you create a class named Group?  You do this by clicking Project | Add Class Module and then pasting the Group code shown in my answer.

Comment: You've got to put more information in the question or people here are not likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Brian M Stafford ... after rename class to Group ... problem solved and working perfect ... thanks a lot brother

Answer (score 0):

I use the Flexgrid control in my VB6 programs sice 2001 up to now and I have no knowledge of any built-in resource that could do it for you. I do a lot of this in the hard way, I mean, searching the grid values through TextMatrix property. To save work I made a custom UserControl using a FlexGrid, so I coded this kind of resource inside it.